# Palm Pre window.scrollY property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webos, palm-pre

Is it possible to get the window.scrollY property in Javascript on the Palm Pre? Doesn't seem to be but maybe there is a secret Palm-ish way?

I've tried:

```
var y = window.scrollY;
var y = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
```

Neither seem to work. Anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, Palm does not care a lot about javascript standards... No API documentation is available and as far as I remember controlling scroll on Palm handsets is not possible.

I can't get UAProf but more informations can be found [here](http://www.handsetdetection.com/devices/properties/Palm/palm_pre_ver1) if you wan't.

Comment: Yes I don't want to set the scrollY I want to read it. Should return -1 if it can't provide it, not 0 since 0 is a valid value.